# Mockito sequential method invocation in `when`

Tags: mockito

For the given:

```
@Mock
View view;
```

I would like when `((View) view.getParent()).getWidth();` is called to return e.g. `400` but without mocking the `getParent()`.

Similar to `when(((View) view.getParent()).getWidth()).thenReturn(400);` (this does not work).

I know it exists (but I cannot find) a setting in Mockito which allows sequential method invocation.

Comment: You can't tell the parent to return 400 without mocking the parent.

Comment: @JBNizet Because of the casting ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `@Mock` to `@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)`. Without that, `view.getParent()` would always return `null`.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Answers;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    View view;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(view.getParent().getWidth()).thenReturn(400);
        assertThat(view.getParent().getWidth()).isEqualTo(400);
    }
}
```

It is a shortcut for creating mock for `view.getParent()` invocation manually, i.e.:

```
View parent = mock(View.class);
when(view.getParent()).thenReturn(parent);
```

[Mockito documentation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) for `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`.

Answer (score 0):

Mykhailo's answer goes into detail about one way to do this automatically with `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`; you could also do it manually, which it sounds like you're trying to avoid, but which is exactly what I would do in your situation.

```
@Mock View view;
@Mock View parent;

when(view.getParent()).thenReturn(parent);
when(parent.getWidth()).thenReturn(400);
```

As JB Nizet said in the comments, you have to mock the parent to make this work. This is because a `@Mock View` isn't a real view, so `getParent` will return `null` unless you stub it otherwise. This means you need to stub `getParent` to return a real 400px-wide view, or stub `getParent` to return a parent view you mock such that `getWidth` returns 400. (There are a few other options, such as using a `@Spy` of a real View, but then your spied-on view would have a real 400px-wide parent and you wouldn't be in this situation.)